# How can I count a specific value in group_by in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and I use groupby to group it by Season. One of the columns of the original df is named Check and consists of True and False. My aim it to count the True values for each group and put it in the new dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

df = ....
df['Check'] = df['Actual'] == df['Prediction']
grouped_per_year = df.groupby('Season')

df_2= pd.DataFrame()
df_2['Seasons'] = total_matches_per_year.keys()
df_2['Successes'] = ''
df_2['Total_Matches'] = list(grouped_per_year.size())
df_2['SR'] = df_2['Successes'] / df_2['Total_Matches']
df_2['Money_In'] = list(grouped_per_year['Money_In'].apply(sum))
df_2['Profit (%)'] = (df_profit['Money_In'] - df_profit['Total_Matches']) / df_profit['Total_Matches'] * 100.
```

I have tried:

```
successes_per_year = grouped_per_year['Pred_Check'].value_counts()
```

but I don't know how to get only the True count.

Comment: Joris's answer works obviously.  You could also do a boolean selection[x==True] combined with count().

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For counting `True`, you can also use `sum` (as True=1 and False=0 when doing a numerical operation):

```
grouped_per_year['Pred_Check'].sum()
```